# How to Set Individual Access from An Imported CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a script that will import a csv and use the information to give or remove access to a service. I am able to remove access to the service but I'm having some trouble with adding access to the service. The csv has the name of the employee, `employeeID`, whether or not they need access to the service, and what access they need to the service (Role and Segment). I have an array that gets me all the `SamAccountName`s of the users who need access to the service and I'm trying to use that array with a `foreach` loop, to iterate through the array and set each users access. The issue I'm having is setting each user's access individually with a `foreach` loop.

[image: Sample of csv]

I imported the csv, then created a variable to get me a list of all the people who need access to the service. Then I created another variable that had a list of all the user's SamAccountName.

```
$test = Import-Csv -LiteralPath "C:\Users\Username\Documents\PS Scripts\test.csv"
$testAdd = $test | Where-Object {$_.ACTION -like "Add*"}
$testAddSam = foreach ($ID in $testAdd."Employee ID"){
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$ID'" -Properties SamAccountName| Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName 
}
```

I then tried to use $testAddSam to set each user's service access,

```
foreach ($SamAccountName in $testAddSam){
    Set-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName -Replace @{serviceRole=$testAdd."Service Role";serviceSegment=$testAdd."Service Segment"} -Credential $creds
}
```

But I get an error stating:

> "Set-ADUser : Multiple values were specified for an attribute that can have only one value".

I know that it's trying to set everything that is in $testAdd."Service Role" to the user's service role attribute, but how would I have it look at the first user in `$testAddSam` and set their service access and then move onto the next user?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$testAdd` is a filtered collection of objects, `$testAdd."Service Role"` and `$testAdd."Service Segment"` would be enumerating **all values** of the properties from that collection. Instead you should be enumerating your CSV line by line and using the values of each row per user:

```bash
$source = 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\PS Scripts\test.csv'
Import-Csv -LiteralPath $source | ForEach-Object {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.ID)) {
        return # skip here
    }

    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.ID)'"
    # if the user could not be found
    if (-not $user) {
        return # skip here, can add logging here too!
    }

    $splatParams = @{
        Credential = $creds
        Identity   = $user
    }

    if ($_.Action -eq 'Add Access') {
        # here we can use `-Replace`, if there is other action such as
        # 'Remove Access' you could add a new condition and use `-Remove` and so on
        $splatParams['Replace'] = @{
            ServiceRole    = $_.'Service Role'
            ServiceSegment = $_.'Service Segment'
        }

        Set-ADuser @splatParams
    }
}
```